# SQL Server 2014 - Restore Encrypted backup on new instance

Tags: sql-server

I have database BAK file that has been encrypted.
I have the certificate,
I have the PVK file
and I have the pass phrase.

What are the exact steps to restore and install the cert on a new SQL Server instance that does not have any encryption setup or 'master key'?
I can not find an answer on line.

Do I need to create a new cert with the certificate?, with the Private key file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you really not try to [Google](https://www.google.com). I got a lot of helpful links when i simply entered [restore an encrypted database SQL Server 2014](https://www.google.com/search?q=restore+an+encrypted+database+SQL+Server+2014&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b).

Comment: yes... did you find the exact steps and commands?

Comment: Yes. This one, for example, looked promising: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Encryption/109028/

Comment: thanks!...  I think the steps are to create the certificate from a file on the new instance

CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'Someseccurepassword'

GO
CREATE CERTIFICATE [MyNewCert] AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM FILE = 'E:\Bak\MSSQL12.INST1\MSSQL\Backup\MyNewCert.cer'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@sswordt0encryptbackup'
, FILE = 'E:\Bak\MSSQL12.INST1\MSSQL\Backup\MyNewCert.pky'
--, ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'P@sswordt0encryptcert'
)